# URLs rewrite - Removing unwanted characters and slashes

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I need to rewrite URL's using **.htaccess** to redirect all users from old sitemap to the new URL's. The old URLs looks like this:

```
http://example.com/a/v/c/document_title1.php
http://example.com/fr/x/1/o/document_title2.php
http://example.com/de/a/a/2/document_title3.php
http://example.com/eng/6/z/z/document_title4.php
```

I need to keep first directory and then remove all sub-directories, including slashes and characters (letters and numbers between /) so the new URLs will look like this:

```
http://example.com/document_title1.php
http://example.com/fr/document_title1.php
http://example.com/de/document_title2.php
http://example.com/eng/document_title3.php
```

I tried various online generators and always got 500 error. Is this something I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this substitution](https://regex101.com/r/iov7Du/2)

Pattern: `(?<=http://example\.com/)(fr/|de/|eng/)?.*(?=document_title\d\.php)`

Replace with: `$1`

This will almost definitely need to include some tweaks, but I'm working with what I was given. In this section `(fr/|de/|eng/)?` you'll need to add `|` for each possible language extension.